# Json serialize data error for handler with JsonIgnore

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I have an exception like this, it's caused by trying to serialize "handler" for hibernate lazy loading.

```
 org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: org.apache.commons.collections.map.HashedMap["results"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->net.pack.tx.model.Proc["client"]->net.pack.tx.model.Client_$$_jvst8e_1a["handler"]);
```

But, I'm using both on Proc and Client classes annotation

```
  @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

I'm also using in parent class (Proc.class) annotation

```
  @JsonManagedReference("client")
  Client client;
```

Exception caused on:

```
   objConverter.write(resultsJson, jsonMimeType,
            new ServletServerHttpResponse(response));
```

How to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Have you try `@JsonIgnore` above your `Client client;` ?

Comment: With @JsonIgnore still generate this exception